# C Program that calculates letter frequencies in strings relative to string length

Tags: c

I'm working on a program that can measure the frequency of letters that appear in a string given by the user. What makes this program a little different is that the frequency I'm trying to obtain for each letter is the evaluation of the amount of times a character appears divided by the total length of the string itself. I'm nearly done with the program but I keep getting all zeroes for all the letters of the alphabet no matter what I do. How can I fix this? This is my program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXCHAR 1000
int main()
{
  int c = 0, count[26] = {0}, x, length = 0;
  double frequency;
  char str[MAXCHAR];

  printf("Enter a string\n");
  gets(str);


   while (str[length] != '\0')
      length++;    

   while (str[c] != '\0') 
   {
   /** Considering characters from 'a' to 'z' only and ignoring others. */

      if (str[c] >= 'a' && str[c] <= 'z') 
      {
         x = str[c] - 'a';
         count[x]++;
      }

      c++;
   }
   printf("%d \n" , length);
   frequency = (count[c]/length);
for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
   printf("%c %lf \n", c + 'a', frequency);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess you may want to convert the int values to double/float before division because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the frequency calculation into the loop and cast `count[c]` or `length` from `int` to `double` to avoid truncating the decimal:

```
for (c = 0; c < 26; c++) {
    frequency = (double)count[c] / length;
    printf("%c %lf \n", c + 'a', frequency);
}
```

Output (where `str = "stack overflow"`):

```
a 0.071429 
b 0.000000 
c 0.071429 
d 0.000000 
e 0.071429 
f 0.071429 
g 0.000000 
h 0.000000 
i 0.000000 
j 0.000000 
k 0.071429 
l 0.071429 
m 0.000000 
n 0.000000 
o 0.142857 
p 0.000000 
q 0.000000 
r 0.071429 
s 0.071429 
t 0.071429 
u 0.000000 
v 0.071429 
w 0.071429 
x 0.000000 
y 0.000000 
z 0.000000
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/PresentFaithfulInversion)

Note that your `length` doesn't include the null-terminating buffer which may lead to logical bugs down the road.

Also, from the [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets):

> Never use gets(). Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the
>   data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because
>   gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer,
>   it is extremely dangerous to use. It has been used to break computer
>   security. Use fgets() instead.

Comment: I didn't notice the data type, but some floating point should work--I don't really see the point of the intermediate variable. Changed to `double`.

Comment: Note: A trick to avoid the cast (and should it be `float` or `double`) is to assign first to match the destination type - and then divide:  `frequency = count[c]; frequency /= length;`

Comment: I see! Thank you so much!